# python getouterframes fails

Tags: python, runtime-error

I am analyzing call stack and it usually works. Now one of program users reports a problem. Log gives me such info:

```
  File "my_prog.py", line 147, in my_proc
  File "scripts/common/Lib/inspect.py", line 1032, in getouterframes
  File "scripts/common/Lib/inspect.py", line 1007, in getframeinfo
  File "scripts/common/Lib/inspect.py", line 528, in findsource
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Any idea why this python lib fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have hit a Python bug, see [issue 17526](http://bugs.python.org/issue17526):

> inspect.findsource raises undocumented error for code objects with empty filename

You are inspecting an object whose filename is set to an empty string.

Either upgrade your Python version, or apply the fix manually; edit `inspect.py` and alter line  528, replacing:

```
if not sourcefile and file[0] + file[-1] != '<>':
```

with:

```
if not sourcefile and file[:1] + file[-1:] != '<>':
```

Python versions 2.7.5 and 3.3.2 and newer include the fix.